# Are "the prisoner broke free from the cell/ the policeman" and "the prisoner broke away from the cell/ the policeman" the same?

Tags: phrase-choice

Are "**the prisoner broke free from the cell/ the policeman**" and "**the prisoner broke away from the cell/ the policeman**" the same?
According to my study,

It seems like "He broke free from the cell/the policeman" involves using physical force. For example, he might use hammers or hands to break the bars  of the cell or hit the policeman

While "He broke away from the cell/the policeman" implies he used tricks not many physical force to do it. He might pick the cell lock and intelligently managed to get out of the cell without being seen.

But I am not sure I am correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone can "break free" or "break away"  from a human grip or hold.

> The prisoner broke free from the guards who were escorting him.
>
> The prisoner broke away from the guards who were escorting him.

But you can only "break free" or "out", not "away", from mechanical restraints.

> The prisoner broke free from his chains.
>
> The prisoner broke out of his chains.
>
> This pirsoner broke away from his chains. <sup>unidiomatic</sup>

Freeing oneself from the  grip of the guards would involve some strength or force, even if it is only a twisting or writhing of the body. But with chains or handcuffs, it could involve a hammer and chisel, or it could involve a bobby-pin, a picking of the lock.

With confining spaces, jail, prison, cell, we normally say "break out";  "free" would sound  a little strange (to this speaker of American English), but it would certainly be understood. "broke away" would not work at all.

> The prisoner broke out of his cell.
>
> The prisoner broke free from his cell. <sup>marginal</sup>
>
> The prisoner broke away from his cell. <sup>unidiomatic</sup>

That might involve some  use of tools, or it might involve only timing and trickery.

In American English you could also use "get" and that verb, unlike "break", doesn't  imply any use of force; it could be 100% guile.

> The prisoner somehow got away from the guards who were escorting him.
>
> The prisoner somehow got free from  his chains.
>
> The prisoner somehow got out of his cell.